# Javascript encoding checker ASCII/UFT8

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding

**Is there a way to replicate `mb_detect_encoding` from PHP with javascript?** I'm trying to recreate something like this.

```
 isAscii("Ã©ton") //false
 isAscii("hello") //true
```

Or is there a way to check if a string has already been encoded with utf-8?

Comment: UTF8 encodes strings into _bytes_.  Strings are just characters; they don't have any encoding.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: My backend is returning me a base64 encoded HTML view to prevent XSS auditor from chrome to block my request, then I decode the view and inject it in a specific ```<div>```, but the encoding is all messed up

Comment: That means you're doing something wrong in encoding or decoding.

Comment: Yes, for many intents and purposes "Strings are just characters". When you need to count them or slice them, they are actually UTF-16 code units. This question doesn't make sense. The HTTP response must have a charset, which is likely handled by your xhr function if you are ending up with the response body in a String. If the string contains Base64 then decoding it gives you a byte array. If the byte array is an HTML document then it will have a document encoding that is either declared within or communicated by/agreed with the person that converted it to Base64.

Comment: Yes, there was a problem with my request, I've fixed it after @SLacks made his comment, and indeed I didn't know what was wrong so the question does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all ASCII characters are inbetween `\x00` and `\x7F` you could simply test if your string matches that range of characters with a RegEx.

The RegEx would be `/^[\x00-\x7F]*$/`, and using the `//.test()` method returns whether or not the input fits the pattern:

```js
function isAscii(str) {
  return /^[\x00-\x7F]*$/.test(str);
}

console.log(isAscii("Ã©ton")) //false
console.log(isAscii("hello")) //true
```

as [@duskwuff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149341/duskwuff) points out, it would be more performant to check if the string contains any characters not from the ASCII set and then return the opposite of that result:

```js
function isAscii(str) {
  return !/[^\x00-\x7f]/.test(str);
}

console.log(isAscii("Ã©ton")) //false
console.log(isAscii("hello")) //true
```

Note however that this is not encoding, it's which set the characters are from.

Comment: A more performant option would be to reverse the condition: search for any one character that is not ASCII (`[^\x00-\x7f]`) and invert the result of `Regex.test`.

Comment: This is perfect! It's working good! Thanks! I'll approve your answer!

Comment: Yes, "this is not encoding, it's which set the characters are from." JavaScript uses Unicode. This function tests for a subset: [`isBlockC0ControlsAndBasicLatin`](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html).